# Is there any throughput limits on the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, api

We are using the REST API to upsert records into Salesforce in real-time, which means there is only ever 1 record to upsert at a time.

For the initial load of data we are going to use the same integration for our 40K records, this means each request will be equate to a single record which is below our 24 hour API usage limit.

What I want to know is, is there any throughput limits that I need to be aware of? i.e. Can I make all 20k requests within 30mins?

Lastly does this differ for custom REST end points that we build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limits to the number of concurrent requests and long-running operations (see [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)). As long as you don't violate any per-transaction limits and per-org limits (e.g. more than 10 requests running longer than 5 seconds each), 20k requests within 30 minutes is feasible. However, if you have a ton of validation rules, workflow rules, etc, you might not be able to perform 20k+ loads in 30 minutes, as that's only 0.09 seconds per record. Increasing your batch size to 200 would allow you to handle far more records at once; it might be worth the time to fix that now in case you need the capacity later. Note that any given request is the same as any other; a custom REST endpoint is subject to the same limits as a standard REST API call.